# Is the integral of any even complex function equal to $0$ on any contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, laurent-series

Is it true that:

$\oint _{C(5i+1,8\sqrt3)} \frac {z}{sh(z)} dz  = \oint _{C(i,\sqrt{10})} \frac {z^2}{(1-cos2z)^4}dz = \oint _{C(\pi + i,4)} \frac {z}{tan(z)} dz = 0$

The problem is that i lost my time finding poles and applying the Residue theorem in order to find the integral of $\oint _{C(1,\sqrt \pi)} \frac {z^4-1}{z^6-1} dz$ which was after all equal to $0$ !

Is the integral of any even function on any contour equal to zero since the term $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series expansion of any even function equal to $0$ ?

Comment: That a function is even just tells you about the residues at $z=0$ vanishes.

Comment: If 2 for example was an essantial pole of an even function we would have the terms: $\frac {1}{(z-2)^4}$ and $\frac {1}{(z-2)^2}$ and ... in the Laurent series expansion of f(z) but not the term $\frac {1}{(z-2)}$ which also means $a_{-1} = 0$. So what would differ the Residue at z = 0 from the Residue at any other point ?

Comment: The fact that an even function fulfils $f(-z)= f(z)$ makes explicitly reference to $z=0$ (which is the only fixed point).

Comment: Ahh so if 2 for example was an essantial pole of an even function we would have terms implying $\frac {1}{(z-2)^4}$ and $\frac {1}{(z-2)^3}$ and $\frac {1}{(z-2)^2}$ and $\frac {1}{(z-2)}$... And the residue Res(f(z),2) would be different from 0!

So Even functions have only even powers of x in their Laurent series ONLY when it is evaluated about 0 !
Is what i'm saying true?

Comment: that is true...